Where can I find a specific screw (pan head #10 wood screw) for a wall-mounted speaker
I have these wall speakers which weigh 13 lbs each. There is a keyhole mount in back for hanging them on the wall. The manual calls for a 2.5"-3" #10 pan head wood screw for mounting to the stud.

I can't seem to locate such a wood screw anywhere that matches that description, only sheet metal screws -- which I am considering but I'm aware they aren't the best for wood applications.
Everbilt has one with a round head that would probably work but I am a little dubious of their quality.
The other option I'm considering is to just go with a quality deck screw but I am unsure the keyhole will fit/hang on it properly as opposed to a screw with a flat bottom.
What is the most correct and most durable screw to use?

Head shape, if it fits should work.  The diameter(#10) is for the weight.

Pretty much any screw whose head is big enough to just fit in the hole, and whose shank is small enough to fit in the slot, and long enough to screw into the stud, will work.

Nobody is going to provide some caution regarding putting a 3" screw into a stud? I would be a little concerned about hitting live romex running through the center of the stud...

"Sheet metal" screws will work fine in wood.  drywall screws will also work in the application despite having a bugle head instead of a pan head.
The screw in the illustration is actually a sheet metal screw, a wood screw would have a smooth part instead of being fully threaded.

Visit an old-school hardware store and I'm sure they'll have what you need.  Just make sure to actually hit a stud and not just into drywall.

There's almost no screw in existence of reasonable size which won't carry 13 lbs. just fine. Find one which fits the keyhole and penetrates wood at least an inch (but ideally not more than 1-1/4" to protect wiring). It'll need a pointed tip and not have very fine machine threads. (A machine screw would actually work fine if piloted properly.)
I'd also have no concerns about using suitable hollow wall anchors if stud location is a problem. I particularly like expandable metal sleeve types for this application because they clamp to both faces of the drywall and allow you to adjust screw position afterward. They're readily available.

source
One other suggestion is to use some poster putty on the bottom corners of the speaker. This will help prevent vibration and keep the speaker from being inadvertently bumped off the screw. That stuff is pretty strong in shear once it sets a bit. Removable double-sided foam tape would also work.

Wood is softer than sheet metal. When anchoring into wood, a person Must use a wood screw. A wood screw has a what is call an 'aggressive' thread. The thread is deeper and spaced further apart than a sheet metal screw.
For the length of the screw. Your instruction state to leave 1/4" exposed, for hanging the speaker. Add 1/2" for the thickness of the drywall. Then add 1 1/4" for actually anchoring into the wood wall stud. That adds up to 2" inches of wood screw length.
I have found pan head wood screws at the 'Lowes' home supply stores.
